# Resize elements within a flex container when using Svelte #if blocks

Tags: flexbox, svelte, svelte-component, svelte-transition

I am using Svelte and flexbox to to add and remove elements from a container, while dynamically resizing permanent elements inside the container to always take up the remaining space.

I'd like to have added and removed elements transition in and out with svelte "fly."

**Here is the problem: the permanent elements jump to their new sizes right away awkwardly rather than animating smoothly along with the entering/exiting elements.  How do I make the permanent elements animate as they are resizing?**

I know this can be done with animate "flip" but that is only allowed within an #each block.  I am hoping to use #if bocks to control elements entering and exiting.

I have a [repl with a sample](https://svelte.dev/repl/8b50f7f281674602bcf7a574dd7d64f3?version=3.42.4), but I'll also show the code below.

JS

```
import { fly } from 'svelte/transition'
let add = false;
```

HTML

```
<main>
{#if add}
    <div transition:fly="{{ y: -200, duration: 2000 }}" class='box' id='add'>
        Added element
</div>
{/if}

<div class='box' id='permanent'>
    I would like this element resize smoothly when a new elements is added to the parent container.  Can I do this without an each block, though?
</div>

<button on:click={() => add = !add}>
    {add ? 'Remove ' : 'Add '} element
</button>
```

CSS

```
main {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 10px;
}

.box {
    border: 1px solid black;
    min-height: 50px;
}

#permanent {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
```